# How to paste transposed data to new rows in Pandas Excel

Tags: python, pandas

Pls let me know Pandas in excel.

```
    A   B   C
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
```

I want to select B column value
4,
5,
6

and paste to another excel sheet with row direction. Please help me,,

```
B   4   5   6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Use column filtering to select 'B' then convert the pd.Series to a dataframe using `to_frame` and then transpose, T.  Lastly, use `to_excel`:

```
df['B'].to_frame().T.to_excel('b.xlsx')
```

Output:

[image]

#### Per comment below

Use `startrow` and `startcol` parameters:

```
df['B'].to_frame().T.to_excel('b1.xlsx', startrow=2, startcol=2)
```

Output:

[image]

### Different Excel sheet:

```
df['B'].to_frame().T.to_excel('b3.xlsx', startrow=2, startcol=2, sheet_name='SheetNew')
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  actually I want to specific cell in another sheet ,,